# Grammar about present tense in a conditional phrase

Tags: grammaticality, conditional-constructions, present-tense

Which one is the correct one?

> If the worker [verb] something, the company will show something.
>   If the worker [verb] something, the company shows something.

The context is that I am writing documentation for functions of the workers in my employ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is similar to "When we know what she decides, we will see what to do." The clause starting with *if* uses the present tense; the other clause should use *will*.

> If the worker [verb] something, the company will show something.

> If the worker also works Saturday, the company will show its appreciation.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the first example:

> If the worker asks about a company policy, the company will show a presentation.

The first condition should lead to the following occurrence, but its not a direct cause/action relationship in that something else could possibly be done.

Similar to the second example:

> If the worker writes an inappropriate email, the company deletes it.

In this case, the first condition always leads to the following occurrence. It could be automatic due to the email system programming.

Also, in your phrase "I am writing documentations for functions of the workers in my employee", I think you mean

> I am writing **documentation** for functions of the workers in my **employ(ment)**,

if you are meaning you are their supervisor.  You could also say

> I am writing **documentation** for functions of the workers **under my supervision**.

And *documentation* is understood to be the plural form.